# The cookies are not sent to the server on Safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, safari, cross-browser

I have cookies set on the **B domain**(https://b.com/profile)

When I visit a page under **A domain** and click on a link with attribute `href='https://b.com/profile'`, the GET request does not contain the cookies belongs to the B domain.

If I visit the page https://b.com/profile, the cookies exist and sent to the server successfully.

Tested on Chrome & Firefox and all work as expected.

My safari version is Version 12.0 (14606.1.36.1.9) on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the cookies, I noticed the cookies set with `SameSite=None` are changed to `SameSite=Strict`. And found another discussion relate to a bug of Safari. [Safari not sending cookie even after setting SameSite=None; Secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525719/safari-not-sending-cookie-even-after-setting-samesite-none-secure)