# Best strategy for storing and maintaining JWT refresh tokens in the database?

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, refresh-token

I have a mobile app that implements JWT authentication with the backend. Access tokens are short-lived (1h) and are not stored on the backend. Now for the refresh tokens:

1. If refresh tokens have an expiration it means users will be periodically logged out which is highly undesirable from the business standpoint, it can harm user retention. Is there a way to avoid this without weakening the security, e.g. making refresh tokens "eternal"?
2. What's the best way of storing and cleaning up the refresh token table that would prevent accumulation of unused tokens? Say I have the following table structure: `user_id`, `device_id`, `refresh_token`. If the strategy is to never expire the refresh tokens, the only way to invalidate them would be when a user logs out. However, users can also delete the app, lose or damage the device, or have their `device_id` changed for whatever reason. One solution I can think of is to have a `refreshed_at` timestamp that will allow to invalidate the tokens say after a few months of non-use. Any other known tricks?
3. Say I use a shared secret string in addition to the refresh token when refreshing access tokens, is my understanding correct that if all 3 are compromised (access token, refresh token and shared secret), there's nothing I can do about it? What are the best practices for the `refresh` API call?

Answer (score 8):

A couple of points to add, based on having worked with Ping Federate in the past, and having used their implementation:

- Store a refresh token SHA256 hash rather than the token itself, so that no rogue employee can steal and use refresh tokens
- Include the client_id and issued_at / expires_at fields. This enables an administrator to find and revoke refresh tokens by application, user and time.

Comment: Excellent idea with hashing!

Answer (score 3):

Eternal refresh tokens do increase risk. To offset this, you could weaken the tokens that are issued during a refresh. To accomplish this, you could have an expiration time on a scope. Then, as the refresh happens, the new tokens have fewer and fewer scopes. Later, if the user is trying to do something high-risk, they would have to login again and prove control of their original credential. I think the business could probably live with this. ([More on this idea](https://developer.curity.io/docs/latest/token-service-admin-guide/scopes.html#scope-lifetime) can be found here.)

Your idea of keeping the `refreshed_at` is probably the way to avoid perpetual growth of the refresh token table. If the user does logout though, can't you delete the refresh tokens? There will some logout endpoint, so behind that do the cleanup. That way, your `refreshed_at` is only for stuff that slips between the cracks.

I don't see what the secret string does to help. It's essentially another "token" and all are bearer tokens, so I'd skip this. For more info about protecting the threats against the refresh flow, checkout [section 4.5 of RFC 6819](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.5). Also, checkout [section 4.12 of the OAuth security BCP](https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-15.html#name-refresh-token-protection) (that's only an RFC).

Comment: Thanks, very useful! Users don't always log out, they can also delete the app without logging out, which happens a lot. Similarly for web clients people tend to clean up cookies and other storage, also in latest Safari versions somehow cookies disappear by themselves - I still can't figure out why this happens. So `refreshed_at` that's let's say a few months old (depending on the nature of your app) may be a good point when you can safely remove the record, I'm thinking.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652141/150435 There's a bug in some old Safari versions where SameSite=None gets treated as SameSite=Strict To work around that, you will probably have to do browser detection.